# Python: create SVG

Tags: python, svg

What I want is to create some electrical symbols (transistor, capacitor, diode...) and than to use them like a puzzle elements to create electrical scheme drawing and save it as one SVG file.

My idea is

- Use some kind of scheme for SVG (like XML Scheme) to create complex electrical symbols out of basic shapes: lines, circles, square...
- Use instances of those symbols, with coordinates (which I load in Python) to put them in the right place in final electrical scheme
- Save it as .SVG

What is the best way to do that? (SVGFig looks like it would do it, but I can't find similar examples)
Examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, not sure if it helps you, but there was a program, called Dia diagram editor, meant for drawing SVGs and equipped with Python command line. It's quite glitchy, though, but at least it has a good set of electrical symbols within and works with SVG. Good luck!

Here are some examples:

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/dia-list/2010-August/msg00014.html

https://live.gnome.org/Dia/Python

Answer (score 0):

Try [svgwrite](https://pypi.org/project/svgwrite/). It's no longer in active development, but the sample script seems to work. You would have to draw your own symbols though.